# Selenium XPath Find Sibling

Tags: selenium, xpath, salesforce, siblings

I'm scripting with Selenium against a Salesforce Lightning App.

I'm having issues getting the actual Available Balance (0.00 GBP), this is held within a div//lightning-formatted-rich-text//span tag

My thoughts are I should be able to locate the `div//lightning-formatted-rich-text//span` tag that contains the text 'Available Balance' and then navigate from that div tag to the div tag that contains the **0.00 GBP** text, and get the text from there - but I'm not sure how to do this....? Here's a screenshot of the code:

[image]

Comment: Please share HTML in text format and which language bindings you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below xpath should work

//span[text()='Available Balance']/../../following-sibling::div[4]//span

Comment: Thanks very much! - Worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Available Balance']//following::div[contains(@class, 'border_bottom')]//span")).getText();
```

Comment: This actually gave me the Account Number - but thanks anyway :).

Comment: ok :) I thought it is always better to avoid indices like div[4], since there can be some div element added in between and you need to change your index every time during maintenance.